# Is mutex in pthread library in c++ the same like synchronized keyword from Java

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, mutex

Is `mutex` in `pthread` library in `c++` the same like `synchronized` keyword from `Java` (whatever call functions I put inside is thread safe)?
I have list of cities

```
pthread_t thread1;

    class City{
    public:
    std::string name;
    int citizens;
    std::string state;
    std::string it_company;
    };

    pthread_mutex_t lock1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    std::list<City> cities;

    void* manage_cities(void*){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        work_on_every_instance_of_list();//works on list cities
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }

    /*
    * This function is called periodically
    */
    void update_cities(){
        pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, &manage_cities, NULL);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        for(std::list<City>::iterator iter=cities.begin();iter!=cities.end();++iter){
            std::cout<<(*iter).name<<"\n";
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }
```

It throws exception in iteration like `Access location`. Is this right way to do or I misunderstood mutexes ?

Comment: I'm sure someone else will give a better answer, but: The `synchronized` keyword is a high level synchronization mechanism. `mutex` is a low level locking primitive which is used a lot in synchronization.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, and no.

The binding between a PThreads mutex and its resources is a lot less strict than you'll find in Java.

With Java, `synchronized` protects a specific thing, as per the language definition, such as function, data item and so on.

You can certainly do the same thing in PThreads if you keep tight control over the resources being accessed but there are some differences I can think of off the top of my head.

First, because `syncronized` applies at the point where an object is defined, there's no getting around the access controls. Java itself will guarantee that someone using the resource will have to wait until they get a lock.

PThreads, on the other hand, is perfectly happy if you do something with the resource *without* first obtaining the lock (there's a "disconnect" between the mutex and the resources it protects that *you* have to manage actively). There's a good chance that will cause you grief but it's under your control whether or not you obtain a lock before accessing the resource.

Secondly, this disconnect allows an extra bit of flexibility: if you think of an array in Java that needs protecting, you tend to lock the entire array. PThreads allows an easier way (in my opinion, anyway) to protect *parts* of resources. Think of an array of 1000 items and ten mutexes, with the first mutex protecting items 0 through 99, the second protecting items 100 through 199, and so on.

This allows for the possibility of better concurrency since two threads can simultaneously do something to different *parts* of the array without blocking each other. I'm not sure how you'd do that in Java without having to split the array into multiple arrays, which would introduce other problems.

Thirdly, because there's this disconnect between the resource and the mutex, PThreads is able to use a single mutex to protect a wide variety of disparate resources, whereas `synchronized` is tied to a Java "item" of some sort. I'm not convinced that's a *good* thing myself but it is a difference.

Now, don't get me wrong, that may all sound like an advertisement for PThreads over `syncronized` but it's not. The price you pay for added flexibility is the increased likelihood that you'll stuff things up somehow. As with most things, it's a trade-off.

I happen to like Java's synchronisation stuff since it's very easy to use.